# ASP.NET - how to retrieve CSS styles applied by javascript on page postback?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I'm working on a page in an ASP.NET site where certain fields (table rows) are being hidden/displayed by some javascript/jquery code, based on selections made on the page by the user.

When the save button is clicked, in the server side code I want to only save the values of the controls in the rows that are visible, however following post back any style applied to the row (i.e. "display:none;") by the javascript code is not available. I've tried doing the following to determine whether a row is visible:

```
If Not trRef.Attributes.CssStyle.Value.Contains("display:none;")
    'row is visible
End If
```

But the CssStyle property is empty (as I gather the controls have been recreated from the viewstate). I thought I might be able to use Request.Form(control.UniqueID) ([as per this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587167/asp-net-select-items-not-being-posted-back-after-jquery-populates-list)) but it seems this will only retrieve the value of a control, and nothing else?

How can I determine whether these rows are visible on post back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styles are not posted to the server, just form values.

You'll need to generate a different mechanism. For instance a hidden field containing visible rows (or hidden ones)  indexes separated by comman and you'd process this hidden field on the server.

Comment: Ah ok, so a hidden field containing the IDs (or whatever) of rows that are hidden or visible ... that's rather messy, but I'll take a look, thanks.

Comment: This was my solution - a hidden text box with comma separated list of hidden row indexes, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to ask yourself *why* certain rows are hidden/visible and, if there's a good reason, make sure you're tracking facts related to *that* and using *that* to hide/show  elements instead of depending upon some state of elements themselves.